# Set Configuration file size in Cherrypy

Tags: python, webserver, cherrypy

I want to set the max size for my error file for my cherrypy server. I'm using a global configuration file for my project and am just looking an answer for this type of configuration. No dictionaries at runtime. This is what I've tried:

```
[global]
server.socket_host = '0.0.0.0'
server.socket_port = 80
server.response.stream = True
server.thread_pool = 1000
log.error_file = 'error.log'
logging.max_bytes = 10240
```

I can't find any documentation on how to do this from a configuration file. The only thing I've found is making a dictionary at runtime. This is not applicable in my case. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I would look into the rotating error log.  You may be able to use the limit and then have the file overwrite itself by using the same name.  Or checkout how the backupcount is used.

https://docs.cherrypy.org/en/3.3.0/refman/_cplogging.html#custom-handlers

```
# Make a new RotatingFileHandler for the error log.
fname = getattr(log, "rot_error_file", "error.log")
h = handlers.RotatingFileHandler(fname, 'a', maxBytes, backupCount)
h.setLevel(DEBUG) 
h.setFormatter(_cplogging.logfmt)
log.error_log.addHandler(h)
```